# Can someone help me with my program keeping a counter in python

Tags: python-3.x

I need this program to generate 100 numbers and then count how many evens an odds there is. I am having trouble with the counting part for some reason.

```
import random

def main():
    for x in range(101):
        number = random.randint(1, 100)
        print(number)
        evenNum = even(number)


    print("Total amount of even numbers: ", evenNum)
    print("Total amount of odd numbers: ", 100 - evenNum)


def even(number):
    count = 0
    if (number % 2) == 0:
        status = True
    else:
        status = False

    if status == True:
        count = count + 1
    return count


main()
```

I can get the program to tell me if the last number is even or odd but I cant get it to keep a running count on all the random even numbers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the Counter class:

```
import collections
import random

cnt = collections.Counter()
for i in range(101):
  number = random.randint(1, 100)
  if number % 2 == 0:
    cnt['even'] += 1
  else:
    cnt['odd'] += 1
print(cnt)
```

Comment: This is increasing complexity by introducing unnecessary abstractions.

Comment: Isn't this the purpose of the counter class?

Comment: No, it is not. Right now you're using the `Counter` class as a very complicated pair of variables.

Comment: It's not very complicated you just save a variable. You will have to write: print("Total amount of even numbers: ", num_even), print("Total amount of odd numbers: ", 100-num_even) I will just have to write print cnt.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `count` gets set to 0 every time you run function `even`.

Move this counter variable to `main`.

---

You could also very succinctly write what you're doing like such:

```
num_even = sum(random.randint(1, 100) % 2 == 0 for _ in range(101))
```

Comment: To add to this, have the function return whether or not a number is even, then increment the even count if it is.